# Center enumerate in tcolorbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, tcolorbox

I have been trying to center an enumerate included in a tcolorbox and it does not work.

My code is:

```
\subsection*{Section Name}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Heading)} Decription of Heading
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)},font={\color{red!50!black}\bfseries},noitemsep]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \item Third Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

My output stays not centered like this:
[image]

I have also tried the `\centering` command, but the result stays the same. Anyone ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `itemize` environment uses up all the current line width.

You could use `varwidth`, but the output is far from being pretty, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\centering
\textbf{Heading)} Decription of Heading

\medskip

\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)},font={\color{red!50!black}\bfseries},noitemsep]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \item Third Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine, thank you! I have another problem, I also use the \usepackage{hyperref} package, which in combination with your solution does not work. Do you know why ?

Comment: @TinaKrutzenbichler `varwidth` containing an itemized list can't work with `hyperref`. It has to do with how `hyperref` wants to set the anchors for the hyperlinks.

Comment: Is there any way, I can can deactivate the hyperref package to use the varwidth for certain sections?

Comment: @TinaKrutzenbichler Sorry, but I can't see how.